# trying to use @font-family

Tags: html, css, font-family

I am making a basic informational website. In my CSS file I have the following:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "Nilland";
    src: local('Nilland.ttf');
}

body{
    background: #FFF;
    font-size:14px;
    font-family: Nilland;
}
```

The .ttf file is in the same directory as the index.html file. Why is this not working?

Comment: http://www.fontspring.com/blog/the-new-bulletproof-font-face-syntax you need multiple font file types and syntaxes to get it to work in all browsers.

Comment: may be your ttf file is not supported in your browser. Try to generate some more web-front by visiting here http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the ttf files in the folder where the css file is.
The path in the css file is relative to the css-file, not the html file

Comment: This worked! I will try the other suggestions to make it cross browser compatible

Answer (score 2):

You need to include all types of your font instead of only `.ttf`, should be something like:

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'Nilland';
src: url('Nilland.eot'); 
src: url('Nilland.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('Nilland.woff') format('woff'),
     url('Nilland.ttf')  format('truetype'),
     url('Nilland.svg#Nilland') format('svg');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying the complete path

Answer (score 0):

@Felix is right although; try separate block for normal and bold font. Use svg and other formats for multiple browser compatibility and path may be issue not to work.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Nilland';
    src: url('../fonts/Nilland.ttf') format('truetype'), url('fonts/Nilland.svg') format('svg');
    src: url('../fonts/Nilland.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: "Nilland";
    src: url("../fonts/Nilland.ttf") format('truetype');
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: normal;
}
```